# JavaScript store procedure to render REGEXP_REPLACE(variable1::string, '@|T|Z|\\(GMT-04:00\\))',' ')) >= timestamp

Tags: javascript, sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regexp-replace

I am trying to render the following line in the stored procedure written in javascript -

```
------Expected output------ 
select val1 from tableName where REGEXP_REPLACE(var1, '@|T|Z|\\(GMT-04:00\\))',' ')) >= date1
```

At present the code looks like this in the stored procedure -

```
----Actual code--------
SELECT val1 from tableName where REGEXP_REPLACE(var1,''@|T|Z|\\\\\\\\(GMT-04:00\\\\\\\\))'', '' '')) >= date1
```

The above code does result in the expected output, however I am trying to optimize this solution, and looking for cleaner way to achieve this final result. Any suggestions are appreciated. TIA.

Comment: the paren `)` in the REGEX is unblanced, is that intended? as are the paren around the REGEXP_REPLACE, was that in a to_date?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of methods that might work for you.

```
SELECT 
    column1,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(column1, '@|T|Z|\\(GMT-04:00\\)',' ') || '!' as r1,
    LEFT(column1, LENGTH(column1)-13) || '!' as hack1,
    iff(column1 ILIKE '%(GMT%', substr(column1, 1, position('(', column1)-3), column1  ) || '!' as hack2
FROM values
    ('2021-01-22 03:40:12.000 T(GMT-04:00)'), 
    ('2021-01-22 03:40:12.000 @(GMT-04:00)'), 
    ('2021-01-22 03:40:12.000 Z(GMT-04:00)'), 
    (to_char(current_timestamp))
```

the concat of `|` is to show the effect of white space matching.

| COLUMN1 | R1 | HACK1 | HACK2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-22 03:40:12.000 T(GMT-04:00) | 2021-01-22 03:40:12.000 ! | 2021-01-22 03:40:12.000! | 2021-01-22 03:40:12.000! |
| 2021-01-22 03:40:12.000 @(GMT-04:00) | 2021-01-22 03:40:12.000 ! | 2021-01-22 03:40:12.000! | 2021-01-22 03:40:12.000! |
| 2021-01-22 03:40:12.000 Z(GMT-04:00) | 2021-01-22 03:40:12.000 ! | 2021-01-22 03:40:12.000! | 2021-01-22 03:40:12.000! |
| 2022-01-21 18:50:43.554 -0800 | 2022-01-21 18:50:43.554 -0800! | 2022-01-21 18:50! | 2022-01-21 18:50:43.554 -0800! |